# How to create checkbox for toolbar?

Tags: java, checkbox, jpanel

I got JCheckBoxMenuItem, but i don't know how to make it useful. When you checked a JCheckBoxMenuItem, then it shows Toolbar and if it is not checked not show it.

```
if(Toolbarbox.isSelected()==true) // if check box is checked
   Toolbar.setEnabled(true);  //enable Jpanel

else   // if check box unchecked   
   Toolbar.setEnabled(false);  //disable Jpanel
```

i am using that code but it not work, any solutions?

**THANKS FOR ANSWERS**

Comment: You should add more code. We can't see where this method is invoked. We don't see how and what you instantiate.

Comment: there is a lot of code i can sent you a whole program

Comment: @LukaToni Do not send all code. Try to reduce your code to a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) and show us the relevant code reproducing the issue you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the body of your function like this:

```
Toolbar.setVisible(!Toolbar.isVisible());
```